# On Laravel, when select option then change the div on laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-8

In laravel i need some help, i am new for laravel,
when select the option , then change the div if any one this
here is code please check

```
<select name="question_type_id" class="div-toggle" data-target=".my-info-1">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Question Type</option>
    @foreach($question_type as $questy)
        <option value="{{$questy->id}}">{{$questy->question_type_name}}</option> 
    @endforeach  
</select>
```

This is db structure which is store the options in the image link please check
http://mrshineonline.com/images/database.png
div for changing is

```
<div class="1 box">
    here multiple choice options
</div>
<div class="2 box">
    Here fill in the blank options
</div>
```

Comment: What div do you wanna change? What are the options? You will have to provide more information.

Comment: Option values stored dynamically, option1 : Multiple choice questions, option2 : Filling the blanks, option3: True or Flase, i need div change related this, please help me if you have any idea , i am new for laravel

Answer (score 1):

This is with jquery. You can do it with vanilla js also but you provided no info

```
<select name="question_type_id" class="div-toggle" data-target=".my-info-1">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Question Type</option>
    @foreach($question_type as $questy)
        <option value="{{$questy->id}}" >{{$questy->question_type_name}}</option> 
    @endforeach  
</select>
@foreach($question_type as $questy)
<div class="toggles-{{ $questy->id }}" class="hidden">
 ...
</div>
@endforeach

<script>
(function() {
    var els = $("div[class^='toggles-']");

    $('.div-toggle').change(function(event) {
        els.hide();
        $('.toggles-' + event.target.value).show();
    });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: not working sir, it is showing all divs at a time